# flickr C# monodroid help required

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.android

I need to use flickr in my application. Is there any Flickr C# API for monodroid?
I am using Monodevelop version 3.0.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlickrNet - http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/ - claims to work with Mono and MonoTouch - so feel free to try it with MonoDroid too!

(I know https://github.com/migueldeicaza/OpenFlowSharp used an earlier version with a patch)

Comment: hey I had checked it, it says it supports mono, but I don't know what to download from here?